# Second VirtualHost returns "This site can’t be reached" - Wamp

Tags: apache-http-server, php, wamp, wordpress, phpmyadmin

It's a mystery. I've created a second VH to use with WAMP.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName dev.sitetest.com
 ServerAlias dev.sitetest.com
 DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/client/sitetest/web/"
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   dev.sitetest.com
::1 dev.sitetest.com
```

Now, I started back my WAMP server, the icon is green, I'm not using Skype, and my other VH is working fine (which is a dev.stuff.com kind of url). I've copied that other VH lines for the httpd-vhosts.conf and the hosts files.

If I try dev.sitetest.com in my browser, I get a "This site can’t be reached dev.vestamtl.com refused to connect." error.

If I try localhost/client/sitetest/, I see all the files and folders at the root of my project.

My settings:

```
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.2.18 Server at localhost Port 80
```

And here's my Apache_error.log file from my last restart:

```
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:03.642285 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14936:tid 648] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:05.673050 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13348:tid 580] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:05.704294 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14936:tid 648] AH00430: Parent: Child process 13348 exited successfully.
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:08.281814 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 9536:tid 648] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:08.328677 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9536:tid 648] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.2.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:08.328677 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9536:tid 648] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Mar 28 2019 11:59:33
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:08.328677 2019] [core:notice] [pid 9536:tid 648] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.39\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39'
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:08.328677 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9536:tid 648] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3104
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:09.250367 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 3104:tid 576] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Jul 10 16:50:09.297200 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3104:tid 576] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

What am I missing? Help.